# SSRS - Reportviewer Export to pdf gets truncated and breaks into pages

Tags: image, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, export-to-pdf

I have created rdl file which includes Table of data. Using reportviewer to view the report. If i export the report as word doc it is in the same format and order as in report but in pdf file content gets truncated and breaks in the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/ff21dfb1-fbb9-42f8-8735-515840b7e4ad/) MSDN forum solution worked for me.

The working answer from the above forum post -

> In the Report Properties dialog if I set Page width to 8.27in and Page height to 11.69in then the Page Setup dialog of ReportViewer defaults to A4.
>
> In the Report Properties dialog if I set Page width to 11.69in and Page height to 8.27in then the Page Setup dialog of ReportViewer defaults to A4, and Orientation defaults to Landscape.